# Printing the number of ways a message can be decoded

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, recursion, dynamic-programming

My below solution to the following problem is exceeding the maximum recursion depth. I am looking for any improvements which i can make.

**Problem**

> Alice and Bob need to send secret messages to each other and are
>   discussing ways to encode their messages:
>
> Alice: “Let’s just use a very simple code: We’ll assign ‘A’ the code
>   word 1, ‘B’ will be 2, and so on down to ‘Z’ being assigned 26.”
>
> Bob: “That’s a stupid code, Alice. Suppose I send you the word ‘BEAN’
>   encoded as 25114. You could decode that in many different ways!”
>   Alice: “Sure you could, but what words would you get? Other than
>   ‘BEAN’, you’d get ‘BEAAD’, ‘YAAD’, ‘YAN’, ‘YKD’ and ‘BEKD’. I think
>   you would be able to figure out the correct decoding. And why would
>   you send me the word ‘BEAN’ anyway?” Bob: “OK, maybe that’s a bad
>   example, but I bet you that if you got a string of length 5000 there
>   would be tons of different decodings and with that many you would find
>   at least two different ones that would make sense.” Alice: “How many
>   different decodings?” Bob: “Jillions!”
>
> For some reason, Alice is still unconvinced by Bob’s argument, so she
>   requires a program that will determine how many decodings there can be
>   for a given string using her code.

**Input**

Input will consist of multiple input sets. Each set will consist of a single line of at most 5000 digits representing a valid encryption (for example, no line will begin with a 0). There will be no spaces between the digits. An input line of ‘0’ will terminate the input and should not be processed.

**Output**

For each input set, output the number of possible decodings for the input string. All answers will be within the range of a 64 bit signed integer.

**Example**

Input:

```
25114
1111111111
3333333333
0
```

Output:

```
6
89
1
```

The following is my solution -

```py
def helper_dp(input_val, k, memo):

    if k == 0:
        return 1

    s = len(input_val) - k

    if input_val[s] == '0':
        return 0

    if memo[k] != -1:
        return memo[k]

    result = helper_dp(input_val, k - 1, memo)

    if k >= 2 and int(input_val[s:s+2]) <= 26:
        result += helper_dp(input_val, k - 2, memo)

    memo[k] = result
    return memo[k]


def num_ways_dp(input_num, input_len):
    memo = [-1] * (len(input_num) + 1)
    return helper_dp(input_num, input_len, memo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = input()
    while number != '0':
        print(num_ways_dp(number, len(number)))
        number = input()
```

Problem Link - https://www.spoj.com/problems/ACODE/

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `MAX_LIMIT = 5001`?

Comment: @pacmaninbw If it can be fixed by raising the limit (and on local machines, that's trivial to do by orders of magnitude), that's about as bad as a Time-limit exceeded. And we haven't outlawed those.

Comment: @Linny That's a hold over from my previous code. I will remove that line. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code performs one recursion per character and [recursion depth is limited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3323001). For long inputs, your code will raise `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Replacing recursion with an explicit loop solves the issue.

Also, if you start the calculation at `k = 1` with `memo[-1]` and `memo[0]` properly initialized and then work upwards to `k = len(s)`, the code will become significantly simpler. When calculating `memo[k]`, you only ever access `memo[k-2]` and `memo[k-1]`, so you can store only those. I renamed them `old` and `new`. Here is how it could look like:

```
def num_ways_dp(s):
    old = new = 1
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if int(s[i:i+2]) > 26: old = 0 # no two-digit solutions
        if int(s[i+1]) == '0': new = 0 # no one-digit solutions
        (old, new) = (new, old + new)
    return new

if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = input()
    while number != '0':
        print(num_ways_dp(number))
        number = input()
```

Comment: Your inner loop could be `old, new = new, (old + new) if int(s[i:i+2]) <= 26 else new`. The parenthesis on the right are not needed and on the left you can constrain the ternary to the part where it actually matters.

Comment: Almost, but you forgot to properly handle 0.  In particular, the string "101" has value 1, not 3.

Comment: The updated code is maps "101" to 2.  Still not quite right.  That both version accept invalid string "1001" is not necessarily unreasonable.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG. for the feedback. It now returns 1 and 0 for 101 and 1001.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for the two `not` operators? I find the code easier to understand when the first condition is negated and the second condition is simply `s[i+1] == '0'`.

Comment: @RainerP. I didn't quite understand the logic for the (old, new) = (new, old + new) line

Comment: @strawhatsai - The `(old, new) = (new, old + new)` is equivalent to `(memo[k-2], memo[k-1]) = (memo[k-1], memo[k])`. I store only the latest two `memo`-entries so I need to rename them each time I increment the loop counter.